# DSpace: Difference between columns 'owner' and 'collection_id' on table 'workflowitem'

Tags: postgresql, dspace

What's the difference between columns 'owner' and 'collection_id' on table 'workflowitem' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Owner refers to the user account (EPerson), while collection ID is the identifier for the collection the item is currently processed in.

Reference: DSpace DB Schema
https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Storage+Layer?preview=/45548226/68355659/dspace5.png